# ejs support in nodejs. how I can got started to learning ejs?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to use ejs framework in nodjes which is supported in nodejs through express framework. Do someone know any website or place which make me seen the code then I can get know how to write thing in ejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://embeddedjs.com/
https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs